# Why doesn't my code correctly create a list of tuples?

Tags: python, methods, tuples

```
direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']
class Lexicon(object):

    def scan(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.words    = self.sentence.split()
        self.term = []

        for word in self.words:
            if word in direction:
                part = ('direction','%s' % word)
                self.term.append(word)
            return self.term


lexicon = Lexicon()
```

when I pass in `lexicon.scan('north south east')` I am expecting the return to give me `[('direction','north'),('direction','south'),('direction','east')]`. Instead I get`['north']`. Here is what I want the program to do on the whole.

1. Take a sentence.
2. use scan on that sentence and split the sentence into different words.
3. Have scan check all of the words in the sentence against several lists (this is just the first test on a single list).
4. If a word is found in a list then I want to create a tuple with the first term being the name of the list and the second being the word.
5. I want to create a tuple for words that are not in list, just like the previous but with "Error" instead of a list name.
6. I want to return a list of tuples called term that has all of the different words in it, with their list name or error in the first part of the tuple

Comment: FWIW, I'd put a `direction = set(direction)` in there for efficiency.

Comment: Are you sure sentence, words and term need to be instance variables? It's better to just use local variables instead if they are don't need to be stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
self.term.append(word)
```

should be this:

```
self.term.append(part)
```

You're discarding `part` rather than adding it to `self.term`.

Also, you're `return`ing from within the loop rather than after it - you need to dedent your `return` statement a notch.  Here's the working code:

```
for word in self.words:
    if word in direction:
        part = ('direction','%s' % word)
        self.term.append(part)
return self.term
```

Output:

```
[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south'), ('direction', 'east')]
```

Answer (score 4):

This line right here is indented too far in:

```
return self.term
```

It's part of the body of the `for` loop, so your loop returns prematurely. Drop it down one indentation level.

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
self.term = [('direction', word) for word in self.words if word in direction]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add on top of the other answers, that this is not the best way to get the intersection of two sets. Why not simply use [Python sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
    class Lexicon(object):

        def bar(self, sentence):
            return set(sentence.split()) & set(direction)
```

I find this both clearer and more efficient.